# Creating offline basemap with small size using ArcGIS SDK for Android?

Tags: android, sdk, arcgis-android

I want to develop an app for mobile devices .I'm using ArcGIS SDK for android and i want to have an offline basemap in the app . One solution is use to **tpk** file.but the size of **tpk** is too large for the app ( 70 megabyte) .

Is there any way to create an offline map with small size ?

Is it possible to use vector base map with high performance ?

Is there any API that i can to use offline map with small size ?

Answer (score 2):

I would extract out the basemap in the form as MBTiles, see the Android SDK link below:

[Local MBTiles](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/sample-code/local-mbtiles/)

Answer (score 2):

You can try converting your *.tpk to a [GeoPackage](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/geopackage). The current release of ArcGIS Android v10.2.4 supports vector [geopackage](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/core/geodatabase/Geopackage.html) format. Here is a [blog post](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2014/04/14/support-for-ogc-geopackages-in-arcgis/) about support for geopackage in ArcGIS. The *.mbtiles file used in the LocalMBTiles sample is vector based and is 1.6MB.